# C++ rand() выдает одинаковые числа

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа, динамические-массивы

Я не могу найти в коде ошибку

```
int main()
{
    int N = 0;
    cin >> N;
    int* matrix = new int[N , N + 1];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N +1; j++)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N+1; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i, j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    delete[] matrix;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод
[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]

Answer (score 4):

`int* matrix = new int[N , N + 1];` — вот здесь. И здесь: `matrix[i, j] = rand() % 10;` И еще...

Словом, двумерная матрица — это `[][]`. А то, что написали вы — *оператор запятая*, т.е. в данном контексте по сути просто второе значение, которое после запятой...

Вот и выходит, что вы все время работаете с одномерным масивом.

```
int main()
{
    int N = 0;
    cin >> N;
    int** matrix = new int*[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) matrix[i] = new int[N + 1];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N +1; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N+1; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;
}
```

Comment: Кстати, довольно любопытно, что начиная с C++20, возможность использования оператора запятая непосредственно внутри оператора индексирования (не как часть более сложного выражения) признана устаревшей, и возможно в будущих версиях стандарта будет вовсе удалена. См.: [depr.comma.subscript](http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.comma.subscript).